# Who attacked "the DAO" on 17 June 2016?

Tags: the-dao

Is there any trace or possibility to understand who executed the attack?
What do we know? Heres some:

1. The attacker had at least 25,805.6141471 DAO tokens. All on one address?
2. The attacker executed the attack between time x and time y? What does this imply?
3. ...

Comment: "[...] answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."   This is so wrong, it needs no further comment.

Comment: agree, don't use stackexchange as an iterative discussion thread on an unsolved problem... Perhaps a post mortem question of "What lessons were learned regarding TheDao" should be created in a month or so...