# How can we find "the DAO" attacker on 17 June 2016?

Tags: security, the-dao, anonymity

This question is about the level of anonymity in the system.

I would like to know how anonymous one can be at this ecosystem?

In other words, is it possible to track down an individual responsible for one or more transactions (considering the fact that he is trying to hide himself)?

Comment: if you have a good plan *how* to find him, then we can execute it and answer my question too: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/who-attacked-the-dao-on-17-june-2016?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There's an interesting write-up by Thomas Jay Rush that tries to geolocate the attacker by looking at [transaction patterns across the accounts associated with the attack](http://daodeepdive.com/data/hack_data/) using the [Ethslurp](http://ethslurp.com/) tool.

Post: "[A Clue About the DAO Attacker’s Location?](https://medium.com/@tjayrush/a-clue-about-the-dao-attackers-location-912b9ff29f66#.dlucjw6nm)"

Of course, it's all speculation, but at least there's a degree of thought going into it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an open question. There is a decent likelihood that the attack was not planned long in advance so the hacker might have done mistakes as using addresses that are linkable to their identity. [Here is an excellent overview](https://medium.com/@oaeee/the-attack-story-38f4789b3c3b#.dtrkmpga4) of the accounts involved:

[image: tracking down the attacker]

The hacker was careful and used only ETH from a transaction from shapeshift.

Quoted from [the FAQ](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4os7l5/the_big_thedao_heist_faq/).

---

Update, [ether.camp has an interactive version](http://www.ether.camp/dao-thief.html)!